# Why does Cassandra tell James Cole to stay away from her in Haiti?

Tags: analysis, 12-monkeys-tv

In *12 Monkeys*, Season 1, Episode 3, when James Cole tells Cassandra that he might see her in Haiti she replies:

> "Okay, well, when you're there, you do me a favor, and you stay away
>   from me. Got it?"

Why did she say that? She was wrong about a virus on Haiti and embarrassed herself so why didn't she ask Cole to warn her? Is it just so that the future of events doesn't change?

Also, Jones always warns James not to affect the future and I think that he never did, maybe he can't change the future and all he does is affect the events that already happened in the future?

Answer (score 4):

She wanted him to avoid her because she feared that it might corrupt / fracture both their timelines. She was worried about the safety of both of them. And Cole kind of gets it.

*“Got it. We cross paths, it could kill me.”*